# How to align a flex item when it's very long

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm creating a very simple responsive image gallery, with the least amount of css posible.
I've came up with the following

```
<div class="container">
  <ul class="thumbnail">
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>name goes here</p>
        <p>subname goes here</p>
        <p>year</p>
        <img src="" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.thumbnail {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}

.thumbnail li {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.thumbnail img {
  display: block; /* remove bottom gap */
}

.thumb-caption {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.thumb-caption > * {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

... and the result

https://jsfiddle.net/51yrdk11/

I want to center everything inside the class `thumb-caption`. It could be a `<p>` or `img` tag.

For some reason, when one of the `<p>` in the `thumb-caption` class is very long, it does not center correctly.

Can anybody tell me why and to fix it?

**EDIT**

I know that by using `text-align:center` an the `<p>` tags, it aligns correctly. But, why? Why some are align and the long ones are not align? I need to understand the logic.

Comment: Use `text-align` to target the content within the `p` --> https://jsfiddle.net/sol_b/0LLmndnn/

Comment: i know about text-align: center, but why? i thought that align-items was supposed to align the items. Why some are align and the long ones are not align? I need to understand the logic. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `align-items` is used to align the flex-items. It will not align the inner content of the flex-items.

You have to use `text-align: center` in the `.thumb-caption` class

***Stack Snippet***

```css
/*----- reset -----*/

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p,
ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* end - reset */

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: pink;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}

.thumbnail li {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.thumbnail img {
  display: block;
  /* remove bottom gap */
}

.thumb-caption {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.thumb-caption>* {
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* media queries */

.thumbnail li {
  flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
}


/* end- media queries */

.fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="thumbnail">
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname is very very long, and when it is very long, for some reason, it does not center correctly, why?
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/skh9da22/)**

Comment: i know about text-align: center, but why? i thought that align-items was supposed to align the items. Why some are align and the long ones are not align? I need to understand the logic. Thanks

Comment: @Marco `align-items` aligns the elements themselves. It doesn't align the text contents *within* the elements.

Comment: `align-items` is used to defines how the browser distributes space between and around flex items according to its content. It will align the flex items center but not the flex item inner content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items

Comment: @Bhuwan I get it... the element is the one being aligned not the content inside the element. That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason the smaller text is centered and the long is not, is because it is the `p` element that gets centered, not its content.

What the `align-items: center` does is making the `p` shrink to its content, in opposite to its default, `stretch`, which makes it fill its parent's width, hence when content is too wide it can't center the `p` anymore, as it takes full width.

As you already know, `text-align: center` targeting the `p` element will fix this.

---

*As a note, one of the simplest things one can do, to understand these kind of logics, is to add a border or background color on the element that seems to behave odd, in this case on the `p`, and one will most of the time see what's going on.*

```css
/*----- reset -----*/
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p,
ul,
ol {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
/* end - reset */

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: pink;
}

.thumbnail {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
}

.thumbnail li {
  margin: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.thumbnail img {
  display: block; /* remove bottom gap */
}

.thumb-caption {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

/* for this demo */
.thumb-caption p {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}

.thumb-caption > * {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/* media queries */
.thumbnail li {
  flex-basis: calc((100% / 3) - 20px);
}
/* end- media queries */

.fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="thumbnail">
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname is very very long, and when it is very long, for some reason, it does not center correctly, why?
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div>
        <img class="fluid" src="http://via.placeholder.com/400x400" width="" height="" alt="">
      </div>
      <div class="thumb-caption">
        <p>
          name goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          subname goes here
        </p>
        <p>
          year
        </p>
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/20x15" width="20" height="15" alt="">
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```